# Running 2 OpenVPN on the same box

Tags: ssh, openvpn, openssh

I know I can create two (or more) user accounts with root privileges, and I can access them independtly through SSH sessions. But I don't know how Unix systems work and how they share resources (i.e. network adapters, etc), and if the routing needed by OpenVPN is unique for a system, and can't be shared between logged in users.
Let's say I create two root users. Can I have two different SSH channels? (i.e. OpenSSH opened in port 22 for user1 and port 23 for user2).
Then I would like to start OpenVPN in pararell for each user, and finally use

```
plink root1@1.2.3.4 -D 1080 -P 22
```

`plink root2@1.2.3.4 -D 1081 -P 23` (or -D 1080 if using different machines)
to create a tunnel (a SOCKS port) in two client machines.

This would be the schematic:

```
client1 <--SSH_tunnel--> UNIX_system <--OpenVPN_tunnel1--> VPN Server
client2 <--SSH_tunnel--> UNIX_system <--OpenVPN_tunnel2--> VPN Server
```

Comment: Is it possible that you mix up SSH and OpenVPN?

Comment: No I haven't mixed up anything. They are both part of the same infrastructure I planed. I have added an schematic.

Comment: The infrastructure should be Client - Tunnel - Server only.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN allows IP routing which doesn't care about users. So there is no need to have two tunnels between the same systems.

Comment: OpenVPN can handle multiple tunnels tho, even to the same client host. If you're paranoid.